# Why 'NOT IN' operator not fetching records for the columns which is not having any value?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, comparison

I have a table with a column name **CORP_SERIOUS**,the values of this column can be **1 or 2 or empty**. When I am searching **unknown values** records means **empty** field using **NOT IN** operator i am getting the **count is zero**.

Why the below query is **not fetching** the records for the field which doesn't have `vm.CORP_SERIOUS NOT IN('1','2')`?

Here is the Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
  ( SELECT DISTINCT vm.vaer_no vaer,
    vm.vaer_no_version version,
    vm.priority priority,
    vm.case_reported_in reportedIn,
    vsr.originalreceivedate initialRcvDate,
    vsr.mostrecentinfodate latestRcvDate,
    vsr.primarysourcecountry reportingCountry,
    vsr.occurcountry occurCountry,
    vsrd.primary_source_full_name reporterFullName,
    vsrd.sender_full_name senderFullName,
    vm.record_id recordId,
    vm.notes_flag notesFlag,
    vm.dmi_product product,
    vmf.VAERS_LINKED,
    vm.VAER_STATUS status,
    vm.company_unit_name companyunit,
    FIND_WF_ACTIVITY(vm.record_id,JBPM_PROCESS_INST_ID),
    vmf.CORRESPONDENCE_FLAG corresFlag,
    vmf.READ_UNREAD_CORRESPONDENCE readUnreadCorresp,
    vm.vaer_mode vmode,
    srcDoc.doc_name,
    vsr.seriousnessdecision serious,
    vm.reportduedate reportduedate,
    vm.MANUALLY_LOCKED,
    vm.LOCKED_BY,
    vm.LOCKED_REASON,
    vm.LOCKED_DATE,
    vm.vaer_delete,
    vm.vaer_nullify nullify,
    vm.archived,
    vm.COMPLETION_FLAG,
    vm.ASSIGNED_USER_GROUP,
    COALESCE(vsrd.TEEATESPECIESDECODE,vsrd.SPECIESDECODE,vsrd.OTHERSPECIES,vsrd.TREATEDSPECIES),
    COALESCE(vsrd.ANIMAL_BREEDDECODE,vsrd.TREATED_BREEDDECODE,vsrd.ANIMAL_BREED,vsrd.TREATED_BREED),
    vm.APPROVED_VAER,
    vm.SUBSTANCE_ADDED,
    vm.MULTIPLEBREEDADDED,
    msg_q.MDN_DATE,
    vm.CASE_SOURCE,
    vm.MESSAGENUMB,
    vsr.NULLIFICATIONREASON,
    vm.CREATED_BY,
    vm.ASSESSMENT_SOURCE,
    vm.ASSESSMENT_CLASSIFICATION,
    vm.DMI_VEDDRA_TERM,
    vsr.CASEREGISTRATIONTYPE,
    vm.AUTHORIZATIONCOMPANY,
    vm.E2B_DMI_PRODUCT brandname,
    vm.E2B_SUBSTANCE_ADDED e2bSubstanceAdded,
    vm.ACCOUNT account,
    ACK.record_id ack_recId ,
    vm.SUBMITTED_DELAY
  FROM agvet_vae_info vm,
    agvet_vae_safetyreport vsr,
    agvet_vae_safetyreport_detail vsrd,
    AGVET_VAE_SOURCE_DOC srcDoc,
    AGVET_VAE_FLAGS vmf,
    E2B_MESSAGE_QUEUE msg_q,
    E2B_MESSAGE_ACK ACK
  WHERE vm.fk_avsr_rec_id      = vsr.record_id
  AND vsr.fk_avsrd_rec_id      = vsrd.record_id
  AND srcdoc.record_id(+)      = vm.fk_vet_source_doc_rec_id
  AND vm.IMPORT_FLAG          <> 1
  AND (vm.DRAFT_SUBMIT_FLAG    = 0
  OR vm.DRAFT_SUBMIT_FLAG      = 2)
  AND vm.VAER_NO               = vmf.VAER_NO(+)
  AND vm.E2B_MESSAGE_LIST_TYPE<>01
  AND vm.MESSAGENUMB           = msg_q.MESSAGE_NUMBER(+)
  AND vm.MESSAGENUMB           = ACK.MESSAGE_NUMBER(+)
  AND (vm.assigned_to          = 48626
  OR vm.assigned_to           IS NULL
  OR vm.assigned_to            = 320538
  OR vm.assigned_to            = 320529
  OR vm.assigned_to            = 406699)
  AND EXISTS
    (SELECT *
    FROM jbpm_token jt
    WHERE jt.node_             IN ( 135,140,146,137,132,129,127,148,144 )
    AND jt.processinstance_     = vm.jbpm_process_inst_id
    OR vm.jbpm_process_inst_id IS NULL
    )
  AND ( fn_access_vet_products(48658,vm.RECORD_ID, vm.CASE_REPORTED_IN)=1)
  AND (vm.PRIORITY                                                    IN ( 02 )
  OR vm.PRIORITY                                                      IS NULL)
  AND ( upper(vm.CORP_SERIOUS) NOT                                    IN ('1','2') )
  AND vm.ARCHIVED                                                      = 0
  AND vm.vaer_nullify                                                  = 0
  AND vm.vaer_delete                                                   = 0
  )
```

Comment: Please reduce your query to the minimum required to reproduce your issue. This will help readers to understand your problem, and may even help yourself at this.

Comment: What does your "empty" value look like? `NULL`? Empty String? ...

Comment: `upper(vm.CORP_SERIOUS) NOT IN ('1','2')` makes no sense. Why **UPPER** is used at all when all you need to check not in condition for numeric values?

Comment: Btw, comparisons against `NULL` need special considerations, see e.g. http://www.techrepublic.com/article/oracle-tip-understand-how-nulls-affect-in-and-exists/5319615/.

Comment: @Hanno Binder: It is (null) that means no  value enetered to that field.

Comment: In that case, have a look at the link I posted. `NULL` may not work with `[NOT] IN`.

Comment: Any comparison to null returns false.

Comment: If you're only searching for `NULL`s, use `WHERE xyz IS NULL` instead of the `NOT IN`. Otherwise you can use something like `WHERE (xyz NOT IN (1,2,4) OR xyz IS NULL)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value NULL means unknown.

```
WHERE vm.CORP_SERIOUS IN('1','2')
```

- is TRUE for '1'
- is FALSE for '3'
- is NULL for NULL

And

```
WHERE vm.CORP_SERIOUS NOT IN('1','2')
```

- is NOT TRUE, hence FALSE for '1'
- is NOT FALSE hence TRUE for '3'
- is NOT NULL, which is again NULL for NULL

As NULL means unknown, we don't know whether the value (that we don't know) is in the given set or not. So the answer is "I don't know", no matter if we ask whether the value is in the list or whether the value is not in the list.

Imagine we don't know John's phone number and I show you some numbers and ask you whether John's number is among them. You can't say yes, you can't say no, you can only say maybe. Same with the DBMS. It cannot tell you TRUE or FALSE, it can only tell you NULL. Now the WHERE clause works like this: The query returns all records for which the given criteria is TRUE. NULL is not TRUE, so the records are not returned.

(Even if NULL itself were in the list, we wouldn't know whether the unknown value in the set is the same as the unknown value in the record. The WHERE clause would still result in NULL. It would make a difference for '3' though: `WHERE vm.CORP_SERIOUS NOT IN('1','2', null)` would suddenly result in NULL too, because the unknown value in the set could or could not be '3'.)

You could ask: Give me all unknown values plus the values in the list.

```
WHERE vm.CORP_SERIOUS IS NULL OR vm.CORP_SERIOUS NOT IN('1','2')
```

Or you could ask:

```
WHERE NVL(vm.CORP_SERIOUS, 'TREAT AS NOT IN THE LIST') NOT IN('1','2')
```

(Well, of course the string 'TREAT AS NOT IN THE LIST' must not be in the list then :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
convert(varchar(50),vm.CORP_SERIOUS) NOT IN('1','2')
```